# Filtering an API List View queryset according to latest timestamp AND Q lookup fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to overwrite my get_queryset method in my generic API List View. I want to query by two fields and get the most recent item.

More specifically I want to Query by project name and by graph name and get only the most recent element.

I am trying to achieve this with Q lookup fields like so:

```
class ListGraphDataAPI(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = GraphSerializer


    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset_list = Graph.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query)&
                Q(project__graph__name__exact=query)
            ).distinct()

        return queryset_list
```

This works in so far that I can filter by name of my graph. the line `Q(project__graph__name__exact=query)` does nothing though. THe problem is that it is a foreign key relation.

Like so:

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self.node_set.all()

    @property
    def edges(self):
        return self.edge_set.all()
```

In my URL I type `http://localhost:8000/graph-data/list/graph/?q=Graph2&q=project2`

My data struture (unfiltered) looks like so:

```
[
    {
        "project": "project1",
        "name": "Graph1",
        "description": "Graph belongs to Projekt1",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 43,
                "name": "25",
                "graph": 94
            }
        ],
        "edges": [
            {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "EdgeForGraph1",
                "graph": 94,
                "source": 43,
                "target": 43
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "project": "project1",
        "name": "Graph1",
        "description": "Graph belongs to Projekt1",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 44,
                "name": "25",
                "graph": 95
            }
        ],
        "edges": [
            {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "EdgeForGraph1",
                "graph": 95,
                "source": 44,
                "target": 44
            }
        ]
    },
```

I tried a bunch of things with the second filter like so:

```
project__graph__icontains=query
project__graph__name=query
```

Also trying to filter by date I tried the `latest` method but could't get it to work thus far.

Any help is of course very much appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance

Ah and maybe it's important that my Project model has the name as primary key (I know, bad practice)

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    start_date              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the clause `order_by()` could help?
If you want the first you can use the `.first()`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Something like:

```
queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=query)&
    Q(project__graph__name__exact=query)
).distinct().order_by('project__graph__timestamp').first()
```

But I see in your question that you do `?q=Graph2&q=project2`, so same name for 2 parameters. You could do `?g=Graph2&p=project2` and then:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    param_graph = self.request.GET.get("g")
    param_project = self.request.GET.get("p")
    if param_graph is null or param_project is null:
        return Graph.objects.all().order_by('timestamp').first()

    return Graph.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=param_graph)&
        Q(project__name__icontains=param_project)
    ).order_by('timestamp', 'project__timestamp').first()
```

Comment: thanks a lot Olivier. That is a good idea... I'd prefer it to only show the one object in the end(the latest) though. Also my bigger problem is that I am failing to query by the foreign key relation and that this line ```Q(project__graph__name__exact=query)``` is not working

Comment: In your question you show this sample `?q=Graph2&q=project2` are you sure you pass 2 parameters with the same name? Or you typed wrong your question?

Comment: Also using the method ```first()```shows me ```TypeError: 'Graph' object is not iterable```

Comment: well my idea is to query by these two parameters. Or what do you mean exactly? sorry

Comment: Or are you saying I have to write two queries for every parameter?

Comment: I've updated my answer I hope you'll get this right **`;)`**

Comment: I've updated in case you have `timestamp` in both `Graph` and `Project`

Comment: Olivier, it worked perfectly to filter by the two params which solves the biggest issue. Thanks so much..... The only problem that remains is, that I can get the latest object with ```order_by('timestamp').first()``` , yet I can't return it in my list_view, since it expects q queryset. Using this method gives me a single object though. (Thus the error with ```not iterable```). Is there a way to filter a queryset down to one object but leaving it as a queryset?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work like this ```order_by('timestamp')[:1]``` . This gives me the first object as a queryset. Thanks a bunch Olivier, very much appreciated!!

Comment: rather by ```order_by('-timestamp')[:1]```